# Getting String inside HTML tag

Tags: python, html

Sorry for my English,

So, i've data like this

```
<dd class="indexed-by">
                                            Journal of Disaster Research | vol: 7 |
                                            issue : 1 | 2012-01-01 | Journal Books                                       </dd>
```

How can i get **"Journal Books"** only from that string?

***Note***: Not only "Journal Books" inside the data, also "Book" and "Papper Publications" exist inside the data.

Comment: Could you show us the full html code or the specific url of your page?

Comment: i can't coz stackflow limit for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = """<dd class="indexed-by">
                                            Journal of Disaster Research | vol: 7 |
                                            issue : 1 | 2012-01-01 | Journal Books                                       </dd> """

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
print(soup.find("dd", class_="indexed-by").text.split("|")[-1].strip())
```

Output:

```
Journal Books
```